# How to remain access to remote access after restart my Windows PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, teamviewer, chrome-remote-desktop

[image]

As soon as I restart my Surface, I can't remote access to it anymore. 
It's just hang ....

I already configure it with Chrome Remote Access & Team Viewer.

If I'm close to it, and wake it up. Only then, it's back online again. 
But what if I'm outside of home, and I can't physically wake it up.

How do I make sure `100%` when I restart my Surface, it always back up online ?

Comment: It should come back on automatically... what do you mean "wake it up". Are you saying wake from sleep? Or like power on?

Comment: After reboot. I don’t know. I assume power on. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

It should come back on automatically. If it doesn't, check out the below list to see if any of these apply:

> If your using Windows, then here are some of the reasons you many not
>   be able to connect.
>
> ```
> You have changed the computer name.
> You are connecting using the IP address and the computer is assigned a new IP address.
> Remote access has been blocked in the Firewall.
> Disabled network card or changed settings.
> Blue screen of death.
> Somebody entered the BIOS as the computer started up.
> Network cable had been unplugged.
> You selected shut down instead of restart.
> ```

Compiled by @stukelly: (https://serverfault.com/questions/10682/can-i-still-log-into-the-remote-computer-after-restarting-it/10684)

My guess is its the firewall. Look and see what the firewall settings are before and after boot to make sure windows isn't defaulting back.